# Select what happens when a button's being pressed

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP (came from .NET) and I am working with Bootstrap. However, I have form featuring a button called "Register". When this button's being pressed, I want to run the register stuff (somewhere located in the same .php-file). Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do that. I just want to run PHP stuff when the button is pressed. That's my code for the particular button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
```

I'd appreciate help.

Comment: pass file path in action attribute of form

Comment: Downvoter: Why don't you tell why you've downvoted the post? Pointless voting..

Comment: When you say "I want to run the register stuff" you mean calling a previously declared function? Or do you mean posting form data to a php page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `name` attribute the the field.

```
<button type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
```

Then using `PHP` check if the button as been pressed.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    // Register.
}
```

**Edit 1**

To set the form as a `post` you need to set it in the form.

```
<form method="post">
     // Your HTML code here.
</form>
```

Make sure you form `method` is `POST`.

**Reading Material**

[Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

[`isset();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I make sure that my form method is POST?

Comment: @Jan check **Edit 2** and read the **Reading Material** section.

Comment: Thanks. Also, do you know how to read out the value of a textbox? Like the name is "password"...? :)

Comment: Read the links above.

Answer (score 0):

This 'PHP stuff' can't be located in the same file containing the form. Make another file that contains this 'PHP Stuff' and in your form tag, use either `GET` or `POST` (POST is recommended) method to pass your form inputs to that PHP page.

Example

```
    <form class="form" method="post" action="YourPHPFileWithPhPStuff.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="USERNAME" name="myusername" id="myusername">

        <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" name="mypassword" id="mypassword">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
```

In your PHP file which is named in this example as `YourPHPFileWithPhPStuff.php`, for this particular example, this is how you pass your POST variables into PHP varaibles

```
    $username=$_POST['myusername'];
    $password=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

You can see that in the div tag in the previous example, the `name="myusername"`, `myusername` is used by PHP to identify the variables. So change it according to what you have in your form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but somehow, I cannot really follow it.

Comment: Wait what? PHP can be in the same file **if** the original file extension is *.php*.

Comment: Can be. But would you recommend doing PHP post into the same file having the form and having the PHP code for processing it in the very same file that has the form? That was the point I was trying to convey. Sorry if it was meant that way

Comment: @Jan Which part are you not able to follow?

Comment: @Titanoboa why wouldn't you? Is there any negatives to this?

Comment: You could explain the difference and the advantages coming with your answers in contrast to Script47's.

Comment: @Script47 Maybe it's just my modus operandi but this is why I wouldn't. I like to keep the PHP processing and the form bit separate. You would end up with parsing errors when you try to parse variables from POST if you are entering the formpage for the first time, right? (assuming php error logging is enabled). Well I could use the `isset()` function, but that just makes things complicated right? Please Enlighten me if this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @Titanoboa How is using `isset` making it more complicated? Also I never stated what you said is wrong, I simply said that your statement that you can't do it in the same file is incorrect.

Comment: @Jan It's pretty clear that there is no advantage or disadvantage and nothing in contrast to the other answer. I just showed you an example that probably suits to whatever you're doing.

Comment: @Script47 Any user (almost 100%) who enters the form page is assumed to be not logged in, right? I just find it unnecessary to perform the check with `isset` within the form page while you could perform the same check on a different php page where the user who enters the page is most certainly guaranteed to be logged in. There is a greater probability that `isset()` will return false in the main form page whereas in the php page dedicated to processing, there is a lesser probability that `isset()` will return false, right? Maybe I am overthinking this, but I do so coz I run stuff on a 128m vps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)